# Animated CSS Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have found a neat animated css progress bar but am struggling extending what what it can do. I have it so that I have an animated progress bar but I want to be able to show the actual percentage once the animated bar has completed - to the right of the bar.

Be grateful for any help

**CSS**

```
.progress_bar 
{
    height: 15px;
    background: orange;
    width: 0%;
    -moz-transition: all 4s ease;
    -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 4s ease;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
    transition: all 4s ease;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="progressBar" class="progress_bar"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 // Assign your element ID to a variable.
var progress = document.getElementById("progressBar");
// Pause the animation for 100 so we can animate from 0 to x%
setTimeout(
  function(){
    progress.style.width = "100%";
  // PHP Version:
  // progress.style.width = <?php echo round($percentage150,2); ?>+"%";
  progress.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
,100);
```

Comment: you want to show percentage only when when progress bar is completed 100%..??

Comment: yes - once the animation is complete

Comment: just have the percentage in a span or something with display:none on it and then once your timer is complete, target that span and display:block

Comment: Try to use this:
http://jsfiddle.net/s4qxtc8m/1/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to insert a hidden element with the percent and show it once the transition is done.

What do you think of this solution ?

```js
// Assign your element ID to a variable.
var progress = document.getElementById("progressBar");
var percent = progress.getElementsByClassName("percent")[0];
// Pause the animation for 100 so we can animate from 0 to x%
setTimeout(
  function() {
    progress.style.width = "100%";
    // PHP Version:
    // progress.style.width = <?php echo round($percentage150,2); ?>+"%";
    progress.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      percent.style.display = "block";
    }, 4100);
    
    
  }, 100);
```

```css
.progress_bar {
  height: 15px;
  background: orange;
  width: 0%;
  -moz-transition: all 4s ease;
  -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 4s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
  transition: all 4s ease;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  
  text-align: center;
}

.progress_bar .percent {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<div id="progressBar" class="progress_bar"><span class="percent">100%</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could give a `delay` on `color` from `transparent` to `black` *via `rgba()`*

here a codepen to play with : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwRRGG

```js
// Assign your element ID to a variable.
var progress = document.getElementById("progressBar");
// Pause the animation for 100 so we can animate from 0 to x%
setTimeout(
  function() {
    progress.style.width = "100%";
    // PHP Version:
    // progress.style.width = <?php echo round($percentage150,2); ?>+"%";
    progress.style.backgroundColor = "green";
     progress.style.color = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
  }, 100);
```

```css
.progress_bar {
  height: 15px;
  background: orange;
  width: 0%;
  -moz-transition: background-color 4s ease, width 4s ease , color 0s 4s;
  
  -webkit-transition: background-color 4s ease, width 4s ease , color 0s  4s;
 
  transition: background-color 4s ease, width 4s ease , color 0s 4s;
 
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  text-align:right
}
```

```html
<div id="progressBar" class="progress_bar">100%</div>
```